# SP Designer 2013 Workflow - Trigger from a record,run through multiple records and update 1 record

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, loop

I have a "Owners" list and a "Metrics" list.

In "Owners" list, each owner has a individual record created for him.

In "Metrics" list,each owner has multiple records assigned to him. In each record,the owner updates a metrics column

In "Owners" list,I want to trigger a workflow for each owner.The workflow should sum up values in the "Metrics" column in "Metrics" list for every owner.The sum should be updated back in "Owners" list for every owner.

How can this be achieved? I tried Looping with SP Designer 2013 workflow ,but that doesn't seem to be working. Looping runs through only one item in the "Metrics" list.

Comment: Can you explain how you did looping in SPD?
Typically, you need send REST request to Metrics list and get items filtered by owner. Then, as you get some JSON DynamicValue, you can iterate on it and sum values as you need.

Comment: You should include your workflow code if you want us to help debug it. As is, this question is too broad to provide a useful answer